# EJB3 eclipseLink on JBOSS EAP6 with POSTGRES no insert in database

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I recovered a project that I migrate from MYSQL to POSTGRES and under JBOSS EAP6 6.4.22.

When in my form I try to insert a new record, I have no error message and the insert is not performed in POSTGRES, but the sequence which serves as primary key is well incremented!

I am using `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` and POSTGRES12.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems i have resolved problem

A rename constraint Postgres ALTER INDEX authors_pkey RENAME TO authors_pkeyb
It seems default constrainte name make problem

B IN persistence.xml file

C Compilation skip test >mvn clean install -DskipTests, otherwise i could not compil

Regards